# How can I add a legend to a goodness of fit plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm using `goodfit` from `vcd` package to produce goodness of fit plots.

I would like to add a legend stating the bars are the actual counts and the dots (connected by the line) are the fit using e.g. Poisson and ML.

`legend` does not work. How can I easily add a legend to this plot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The plot function for `goodfit` objects is using the `grid` graphics system (see `?rootogram` and `getAnywhere(rootogram.default)`).

You have two options:

1. use the rather limited `grid.legend` function (from package `grid`).
2. embed a base graphics legend in the grid plot using the `gridBase` package.

Here is a simple example for the first option:

```
library("vcd")
dummy <- rnbinom(200, size=1.5, prob=0.8)
gf <- goodfit(dummy, type="nbinomial", method="MinChisq")
plot(gf)
pushViewport(viewport(x=unit(0.8, "npc"),
                      y=unit(0.8, "npc"),
                      width=stringWidth("Legend x"),
                      height=unit(6, "line"),
                      name="vp1"))
grid.legend(labels=c("Legend 1", "Legend 2"), pch=1:2)
popViewport()
```

Comment: Thanks., but how do you set the symbols/colors in the legend to match those in the actual graph?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying @rcs's answer to use `grid_legend` (in the `vcd` package along with `goodfit`), which is intended for users (`grid.legend` is an undocumented internal function), and to show a legend specifically geared to this plot.  It would be nice to use `fill=c(NA,"gray")` as in `legend` in base graphics, but it's not implemented in `grid_legend`.

```
library("vcd")
dummy <- rnbinom(200, size=1.5, prob=0.8)
gf <- goodfit(dummy, type="nbinomial", method="MinChisq")
plot(gf)
grid_legend(x=unit(0.8, "npc"),
            y=unit(0.8, "npc"),
            labels=c("est NBinom (MinChiSq)","obs"),
            title="",
            pch=c(16,15),col=c("red","gray"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without a specific example (AFAIK it is not a limitation with `goodfit`), but I would check a few things with `legend`:

1. You can place a legend with `"topright"`, `"bottomleft"`, etc for the argument `x`.
2. You can query the x and y axis limits with `par("usr")`. If the plot is in log scale and you want to place the legend at the maximum value of y, you have to use `10^par("usr")[4]`, and so on.
3. Pass the argument `xpd=NA` to see if you are placing the legend outside of the plotting region and see if you need to set `xjust` or `yjust`.

Comment: won't actually work because `goodfit` uses grid graphics as explained in @rcs's answer ...